# Deploy AWS CDK using AppConfig Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-app-config

I want to deploy a stack using a deployment hosted in AppConfig, but I can't find a method in the documentation that allows to read from it. I searched on: `CfnApplication`, `CfnEnvironment`, `CfnConfigurationProfile`, `CfnDeploymentStrategy` or `CfnDeployment`.

Example of application:

```js
// The goal is to retrieve data stored in AppConfig and return it as `config`
const { config } = new ReadEnvironmentFromAppConfig(app, 'conf')

// Then, use it as argument to deploy other stacks
config.clients.forEach(conf => new MyStack(app, `conf-${conf.name}`, { conf })
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```js
// ./lib/readEnvironmentFromAppConfig

// I have this already
const deployment = new CfnDeployment(/*...*/)

// This is what I want
const config = deployment.fromLastDeployment(/*...*/)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can read API provided by [AWS App Config APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_Operations_Amazon_AppConfig.html).

Below are the JAVA API might be useful for your use case. Look the above docs for other programming languages.

There is a library([`AppConfigClient`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/appconfig/AppConfigClient.html)) which is used to interact with AWS AppConfig.

- [`getDeployment`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/appconfig/AppConfigClient.html#getDeployment(software.amazon.awssdk.services.appconfig.model.GetDeploymentRequest)) this function helps to get the deployments.
- [`getLatestConfiguration`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/appconfigdata/AppConfigDataClient.html#getLatestConfiguration(software.amazon.awssdk.services.appconfigdata.model.GetLatestConfigurationRequest)) - to get Latest Hosted Configuration.
- [`getHostedConfigurationVersion`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/appconfig/AppConfigClient.html#getHostedConfigurationVersion(java.util.function.Consumer)) - to get specific version from the Hosted Configuration.

More Links - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/appconfigdata/package-summary.html

Note:- You have to use AWS Lambda or Some Computing Engine to run these API.